# Prove that $\displaystyle{\lim_{k \to \infty}} k^{n-1} \phi(k) f(kx) \neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

This is a homework problem of my real analysis class.

In the previous parts of this problem, I have shown that for a fixed $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n, m^n)$, we have $$\lim_{k \to \infty}k^{n-1}f(kx) = 0$$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Now I have to prove that for any non-decreasing function $\phi : \mathbb{N} \to [0, \infty)$ with the property $\displaystyle{\lim_{k \to \infty}\phi(k)} = \infty$, the above result fails if $k^{n-1}$ is replaced with $k^{n-1}\phi(k)$.

I currently have no idea at all. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!